# GCloud SDK failing to parse Policy File (JSON)

Tags: gcloud

Feel like I'm missing something obvious here but I can't spot it.

I'm trying to apply an IAM Policy using JSON however gcloud seems to always try and interpret the policy file as YAML.

I've tested this with a YAML equivalent and it works. The `policy.json` file I'm sure is correct, I used `gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${proj}` to create it.

As far as I can tell I've followed the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/projects/set-iam-policy) for this correctly, there doesn't seem to be an extra flag or option to supply for it to read the policy as JSON.

**Command:**

```
gcloud projects set-iam-policy ${proj} policy.json
```

**Error:**

```
ERROR: (gcloud.projects.set-iam-policy) Failed to parse YAML from [policy.json]: while scanning for the next token found character '\t' that cannot start any token
in "policy.json", line 3, column 1
```

**GCloud SDK Version:** 228.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The get-iam-policy output is in YAML format by default. To ensure you have the correct output, try the following command:

```
gcloud projects get-iam-policy your-project --format=json >> policy.json
```

This will write the output formatted to JSON in a policy.json file.